# Raising exception at consumer.poll() when all brokers are down

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

Currently, i have 3 broker cluster kafka environment. kafka-python(2.0.1) throws warning instead of raising an exception when all the brokers are down while polling. I have the following code-

```
while True:
        try:
            raw_messages = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=10000, max_records=5)
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Failed to POll -- {e}")
        for topic_partition, messages in raw_messages.items():
            for msg in messages:
                process(msg)
```

Is it possible to raise Exception when brokers are down while Polling

Comment: Why would you want your consumer to fail? :)

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I don’t want the program to continually retry if the brokers are not up for several hours

Comment: Your consumers and brokers should be independent in terms of monitoring. There are other monitoring tools that can inform you when your broker(s) are down. I wouldn’t say that the consumer should be responsible for resolving the issue on the broker level.